# Как подключить android устройство к другому устройству через Wi-Fi?

Tags: android, wifi

Есть два устройства: Смартфон на андроид с будущим приложением и микроконтроллер (лампочка с вай фай модулем, или элемент умного дома, условно). Что мне нужно написать в android приложении, чтобы их подключить друг к другу (если они уже находятся вместе в одной wi-fi сети), чтобы со смартфона можно было отправлять команды на контроллер?

По сути как bluetooth сокеты, только через wi-fi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если лампочка готовая и она предоставляет REST API, то из android приложения вы вызываете это API по http\https протоколу. Если она работает по какому-то известному в отрасли протоколу (ZigBee, etc), то вам нужно с ним разобраться и сделать свой адаптер на андроиде (как мне кажется, это крутой и сложный путь).

Если вы намереваетесь сделать свою управляемую лампу, то для более высокой отзывчивости я бы рекомендовал использовать веб-сокеты - так вы будете с минимальными задержками видеть в приложении обратную связь от лампочки. Но если отзывчивость не критична, то с небольшими затратами времени вы можете реализовать в лампочке вебсервер, который в зависимости от входящих запросов управляет питанием лампы.

Если будете делать сами, то про https и авторизацию\аутентификацию не забывайте, пожалуйста) Иначе кто-то сможет взломав вашу wifi сеть - управлять всеми устройствами (лампой), и, скорее всего, даже удалённо перепрошивать.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое! Тогда еще вопрос: может ли android приложение "просканировать" wi-fi сеть на наличие подходящих контроллеров? (Контроллер пишет другой человек, но я могу сказать ему что там должно быть). Типа, как законнектить два устройства при подключении к сети, не зная адресов друг друга?

Comment: `может ли android приложение "просканировать" wi-fi сеть на наличие подходящих контроллеров?` Да, это возможно. В локальной сети вы можете отправлять широковещательные сервисные сообщения, что-то типа "ау, здесь есть кто-нибудь? отзовитесь!". Все устройства, которые слушают широковещательные сообщения, должны соответствующим образом отреагировать.

Comment: Другой рабочий подход - сканирование доступного диапазона IP-адресов wifi-сети с последующей попыткой подключения к определённому специфичному порту устройства.